# Nuxt dynamic page slug not changing in asyncdata

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

In a project I'm working on I have a dynamic page in pages/news/_slug.vue

I use the asyncData hook to fetch the data that is used on the page and to set the slugs so the language switcher works. i18n is done with the nuxt/i18n package btw.

When I use the language switcher, the url updates in the browser but the console.log in the asyncData shows that the params.slug doesn't update to the new slug from the browser.

```
async asyncData ({ store, params, $fetchContent }) {
  const type = "news"
  console.log('slug', params.slug)
  const news = await $fetchContent(params.slug, type)
  await store.dispatch('i18n/setRouteParams', {
    en: { slug: news.slugs.en },
    fr: { slug: news.slugs.fr },
    nl: { slug: news.slugs.nl },
  })
  return { news }
},
```

I read that the asyncData only runs on the first page load and shouldn't run again because the same component is loaded by nuxt. But I get the slug console.log in my console 3 times when I switch languages. It just doesn't update to the new slug.
And because of that the fetchContent function doesn't work.

When I reload the page with the new slug, it works fine.
Any ideas how I can make this work?

Comment: Do i need to emit an event for this? Because the <nuxt/> is in another file

Comment: no, I means maybe you can add a `key` based on `slug` for your `<nuxt/>`, maybe `<nuxt :key="$route.fullPath"/>`

Comment: i can see the key updates but the asyncdata keeps using the previous slug